# display PHP variable between tags

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display the query results within a list so that they change dynamically  depending on the query results, how ever I am having trouble trying to display the results on between the  tags

```
<?php
        include 'dbh.php';

        $BOOKNAME=$_GET['bookname'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM book WHERE  
        BOOKNAME LIKE '$BOOKNAME%'   ";
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){}
    ?>


    <html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css">
    <div class="result1"  >
                <ul>
                      <li><a href="#home"> <p><?php echo $row['BOOKNAME'] ;?><p></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Book2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#contact">Book3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#about">Book4</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#about">Book5</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: Well, you might try adding the code in the `while` loop in the first place.

Comment: Side-note: `bookname` is a non-sanitized user-submitted value and leads to SQL injection vulnerability in the current code. Please ensure that values from either `$_POST` or `$_GET` is escaped, e.g. http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code structure is incorrect. In order to display DB fetched values in your html use the following code:

```
<?php
  include 'dbh.php';
  $BOOKNAME=$_GET['bookname'];
  $sql="SELECT * FROM book WHERE  
  BOOKNAME LIKE '$BOOKNAME%'   ";
  $result=$conn->query($sql);
?>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="result1"  >
  <ul>
  <?php
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo '<li><a href="#something"><p>'.$row['BOOKNAME'].'<p></a></li>';
  }
  ?>
  </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try this instead -

<?php
    include 'dbh.php';

    $BOOKNAME=$_GET['bookname'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM book WHERE  
    BOOKNAME LIKE '$BOOKNAME%'   ";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);

?>


<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css">

<div class="result1"  >
            <ul>
                 <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
                  <li><a href="#home"> <p><?php echo $row['BOOKNAME']; ?><p></a></li>
                  <?php } ?>
            </ul>
         </div>

</html>
```